# Facebook C# SDK SignedRequest

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

There is no document on how to use Facebook C# SDK(http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and I am trying to use FacebookSignedRequest.Parse method but it shows and error that its not defined . How do I use it ? I also need to extract values from signed request.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i do it to extract the signed request..

```
FacebookSignedRequest fbsign = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(appsecret, Request.Form["signed_request"]);
```

And then assign it to a dynamic

```
dynamic result = fbsign.Data;
```

Comment: CS0117: 'Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Comment: which version of the sdk are u using?

Comment: The latest from code plex which is  5.0.25 . I opned FacebookSignedRequest class and I dont even see that method as part of the code.Although I see a ParseSignedRequest method as part of FacebookApp .